# SwiftUI: navigation bar shows title for first list item, otherwise shows "Back"

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have basic list and detail views set up as shown below. The problem is that the *first* detail view shows "< Inbox" as the back button while the other rows show "< Back". I've tried various options and places for `.navigationBarTitle` but haven't found any way to solve this.

Main / list view:

```
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(userData.message) { messageSection in
                    Section(header: Text(messageSection.id)) {
                             ForEach(messageSection.messages) { message in
                                NavigationLink(destination: MessageDetail(message: message)) {
                                    MessageRow(message: message)
                                }
                             }
                     }
                 }
                }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Inbox"), displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
```

Detail view:

```
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
...
            }
        }.navigationBarTitle(Text("\(self.message.title) (\(self.message.preview))"), displayMode: .inline)
    }
```

Comment: Can you share a reproducible demo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the title is too long to display in the space allocated for the left bar button, the system uses "Back" as the button title instead.

Comment: Hmm, thanks @LuLuGaGa I will experiment with this! Is it possible to disable this behavior?

Comment: Not that I am aware. It is exactly the same in UIKit, so maybe search for that as well.